# Не получается нормально залить на github page игру на PIXI

Tags: javascript, pixijs

Я сделал небольшую игру про космос на PIXI.JS

Когда я запускаю ее на локальном серваке все ОК, все работает.

Но когда попытался сделать github page выдает ошибку

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

https://tibmt.github.io/CosmicWars/ вот адрес

https://github.com/tibmt/CosmicWars вот кодярник

Comment: по первой ссылке открывается

Comment: но не отображаются изображения(задний фон, космические корабли, лазеры), а также звуки

Comment: У вас неправильный путь для загрузки ресурсов.
В index.html нужно указать

https://tibmt.github.io/CosmicWars/dist/bundle.css

https://tibmt.github.io/CosmicWars/dist/backgroundImgBlue.png

Comment: @sergiix абсолютные пути это плохо

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) поддерживает только два способа публикации проекта:

1. Проектом является всё содержимое **ветки `master`**
2. Проектом является всё содержимое **папки `/docs` ветки `master`**

Скриншот из настроек репозитория:

> [image: скриншот настроек репозитория]

Таким образом, есть два способа организации проекта:

1. В основном репозитории хранятся только исходные коды, собранные файлы по помещаются в отдельный репозиторий, для которого активируется Github Pages
2. В единственном репозитории хранится исходный код проекта, собранные файлы помещаются в папку `/docs`

---

Чуть более подробное про второй способ для webpack'а:

В случае если проект собирается webpack'ом, то для использования второго способа можно изменить папку, куда будут помещаться собранные файлы, для этого есть параметр [`output.path`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path):

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs')
}
```